# How to do weighted moving average with a weight column in Hive/SQL?

Tags: sql, database, hive, relational-database

I have a column `weights` and a column `recall`, I want to calculate the weighted average of `recall` over last 7 days based on `weights`, I already have the query that calculate the moving average with `OVER` statement, however, for calculating the weighted moving average, I think I will have to replace `AVG` the aggregation function to some other functions that takes two columns like `WEIGHTED_AVG(recall, weights)`, is there any way I can do that? Here is my current query.

```
SELECT 
weights,
recall,
avg(recall) OVER(ROWS 6 PRECEDING) AS recall_ma_week FROM TableA;
```

Example `TableA` would be:

```
recall weight
 0.5      3
 0.2      2
 0.3      4
 0.4      2
 0.3      6
 0.2      8
```

And for the last row for example, the number I want to calculate should be 
`0.2*8 + 0.3*6 + ... / (8 + 6 + ...)`, in formula it is, `sum(weight * recall) / sum(weight)`, and when `sum(weight) == 0`, return that value as 1.0. If I were able to create a customized aggregation function that would be awesome but I don't know how to do it in pure SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just use arithmetic:

```
SELECT (sum(recall * weight) OVER (ORDER BY report_created_at ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING) /
        (case when sum(weight) OVER (ORDER BY report_created_at ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING), 0) <> 0
              then sum(weight) OVER (ORDER BY report_created_at ASC ROWS 6 PRECEDING), 0)
         end)
       ) AS recall_ma_week
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! Since `sum(weight)`  might be zero sometimes which will make the devision invalid, would it be able to add a if condition that says when `sum(weight) == 1`, let the value to be 1.

Comment: @xxx222 . . . You can use a `case` expression for that.  SQL has a standard function `nullif()` which makes this easier, but I don't think Hive supports it.